# TestContext properties throws NullReferenceException under NUnit3

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, specflow

This used to work ok with old version of nunit.framework.dll. I recently updated my tests to run with SpecRun. When code reaches my BeforeScenario method:

```
[BeforeScenario]
    public void Init()
    {
        _sw.Start();
        Initialize();

        var env = ConfigManager.GetEnvironment();

        ArrayList categories = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test
   .Properties["Category"] as ArrayList;            // exception here
        if (env.Contains("csp-dev") || env.Contains("csp-qa") || env.Contains(":8445"))
        {
            if (categories != null && categories.Contains(CategoryToExclude))
            {
                Assert.Inconclusive("You tried to run 'Write' test on {0}. Test has been stopped.", env);
            }

        }

        LoginPage.Goto();
        LoginPage.LoginAs(TestConfig.Username).WithPassword(TestConfig.Password).Login();
    }
```

it throws exception for TestContext properties.

Anyone know work around this under new nunit.dll ?

EDIT:
NUnit Version 3.2.1
Re-Sharper 9
VS: 2015 Update 2

Comment: Did you debug and ascertain which property in the statement is null?

Comment: Yes. I used to have it in a "_categories" property. Now this one is null. Sorry for replaying so late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
TestContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest.Properties["Category"] as ArrayList
```

Is always going to be null unless the underlying implementation of NUnit uses an ArrayList - and I can guarantee you it doesn't! The safest way to code this is to write...

```
var categories = TestContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest.Properties["Category"];
```

In the current implementation, this will give you an IList.

I do notice that this interface forces you to know more about NUnit internals than you should have to. You need to know that Categories are implemented as Properties with a specific name. That's OK for our internal code but we should probably add a Categories property to the CurrentTest.

Comment: This did not helped. Still TestContext is null.

Comment: Do you mean that CurrentContext is null? Or is it Properties? Run your code in the debugger to see which it is.

Comment: i have also been trying TestContext.TestDirectory but it gives null reference exception

Comment: You should ask a new question. This one is more than three years old and by now we are talking about different software. When you ask a new question, indicate __where__ you are using `TestContext.TestDirectory` in your code. It only has a value when running a test or (in some versions) when loading one.